# Bash script to mkdir on each line of a file that has been split by a delimiter?

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Trying to figure out how to iterate through a `.txt` file (filemappings.txt) line by line, then split each line using `tab`(`\t`) as a delimiter so that we can create the directory specified on the right of the tab (`mkdir -p`).

Reading filemappings.txt and then splitting each line by `tab`

```
server/ /client/app/
server/a/   /client/app/a/
server/b/   /client/app/b/
```

Would turn into

```
mkdir -p /client/app/
mkdir -p /client/app/a/
mkdir -p /client/app/b/
```

Would `xargs` be a good option? Why or why not?

Comment: BTW -- filenames are allowed to contain tabs (or newlines!), so this isn't a good file format to use for completely arbitrary names; in general, lists of untrusted names should always be NUL-delimited.

Answer (score 5):

```
cut -f 2 filemappings.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

xargs -0 is great for vector operations.

Comment: You probably meant `-f2`? And I think you can use just `xargs -d'\n' ...`. I don't see any point in turning `\n` into `\0` and then using `xargs -0` (maybe there is a difference?).

Comment: @PesaThe: yeah -f1 was a mistake. I turned '\n' into '\0' out of habit rather than knowing there's a reason to do that.

Comment: Because [it wasn't obvious to the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305724/bash-script-to-mkdir-on-each-line-of-a-file-that-has-been-split-by-a-delimiter) perhaps point out that `xargs` will run `mkdir -p` as few times as possible with multiple directories as its arguments. This works fine, and is a good optimization for commands which accept an arbitrary list of file or directory names as arguments; but obviously is less ideal in some other scenarios.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link; the other question is https://stackoverflow.com/q/48308990/874188

Answer (score 3):

You already have an answer telling you how to use `xargs`. In my experience `xargs` is useful when you want to run a simple command on a list of *arguments* that are easy to retrieve. In your example, `xargs` will do nicelly. However, if you want to do something more complicated than run a simple command, you may want to use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b
do
  mkdir -p "$b"
done <filemappings.txt
```

In this special case, `read a b` will read two arguments separated by the defined `IFS` and put each in a different variable. If you are a one-liner lover, you may also do:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b; do mkdir -p "$b"; done <filemappings.txt
```

In this way you may read multiple arguments to apply to any series of commands; something that `xargs` is not well suited to do.

Using `read -r` will read a line literally regardless of any backslashes in it, in case you need to read a line with backslashes.

Also note that some operating systems may allow tabs as part of a file or directory name. That would break the use of the tab as the separator of arguments.

Comment: So, there are a couple of things worth mentioning. 1) Quote: `"$b"` 2) `IFS=\t` won't work. You have to use `IFS=$'\t'` 3) You are changing `IFS` for the rest of the script (that can mess up things). Declare it just for the `read` cmd: `IFS=$'\t' read ...` 4) `read` without `-r` will mange backslashes.

Comment: @PesaThe, I have tested my answer and `IFS=\t` works for me. I have also tried `IFS=$'\t'` and it does not work for me. You are right that defining the variable for a single statement is the way to go, but I have tried it with the `while` statement and it does not work for me. About the quotes around `$b`, you are totally right. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @PesaThe, tested `IFS=$'\t'` in the right place... :-) Now it works. I have fixed that too; as you say, changing `IFS` for the rest of the script is not ideal. Thanks again.

Comment: `IFS=\t` shouldn't work as it splits on literal `t` character :) See this [snippet](https://ideone.com/n8uFe2). Final note: consider adding the `-r` option so that you allow dirs that contain backslashes.

Comment: @PesaThe, consideration accepted, thanks! I have changed the explanation to include the `-r` option.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/\t/{s:^.*\t\t*:mkdir -p ":;s:$:":;p}' filemappings.txt | bash
```

---

1. `sed -n`: only work with lines that contains `tab` (delimiter)
2. `s:^.*\t\t*:mkdir -p :`: change all things from line beggning to `tab` to `mkdir -p`
3. `| bash`: tell `bash` to create folders

Comment: `xargs` runs its command as few times as possible without creating a command line that is too long, so in the case of Joshua's answer, it would run `mkdir` just once, whereas your solution runs it once per line.

Comment: Plus it won't work if there is `"` in the path and it can be used to execute arbitrary code!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `\t` character could also be a part of the file or directory name, and the following command may fail. Assuming the question represents the true form of the input file, one can use:

```
  $ grep -o -P '(?<=\t).*' filemappings.txt | xargs -d'\n' mkdir -p
```

It uses `-P` perl-style regex to get words after the `\t`(TAB) character, then use `-d'\n'` which provides all relevant lines as a single input to `mkdir -p`.

Comment: You are right. `-d'\n'` does scale with large number of input lines. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel --colsep '\t' mkdir -p {2} < filemapping.txt
```